# Cell border width auto increases with contents

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a page using bootstrap and angular. Fixed my layout thru BS and now working on angular. While trying to repeat an image via ng-repeat, I got into this cell border problem and not sure what to do.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th colspan=2 class="text-center">Skill Level</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Forehand: </th>                 
        <td>
            <img class="image star" src="img/star.png"/>
            <img class="image star" src="img/star.png"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

[image: This is how my bootstrap layout was]

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th colspan=2 class="text-center">Skill Level    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="skill in skillLevel">
        <th>
            {{ skill.skillName }}:
        </th>                   
        <td data-ng-repeat="i in makeArray(skill.value) track by $index">
            <img class="image star" src="img/star.png"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: After using ng-repeat now i ended up here :(]

Got this `makeArray` function from a SO thread. I've tried setting `min-width` and `max-width` for the cell, yet no use. Can you help? Thanks.

```
$scope.skillLevel=[
    {'skillName':'HTML', 'value': 1}, 
    {'skillName':'CSS', 'value': 4}, 
    {'skillName':'JS', 'value': 5}, 
    {'skillName':'Bootstrap', 'value': 1}
];
$scope.makeArray=function(number) {
    return new Array(number);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<td data-ng-repeat="i in makeArray(skill.value) track by $index">
<img class="image star" src="img/star.png"/>
</td>
```

to

```
<td>
    <img class="image star" src="img/star.png" data-ng-repeat="i in makeArray(skill.value) track by $index" />
</td>
```

The problem occured when you replicated the `<td>` cells instead of replicating the `<img>` images.